# Custom ViewGroup, last child in a row Match parent to fill all empty space

Tags: android, view, viewgroup, measure

I'm trying to build a custom `ViewGroup base` on DavidPizarro/AutoLabelUI
https://github.com/DavidPizarro/AutoLabelUI

My goal is to create a page that looks like this:
[image]

but this is the closest that I got:

[image]

This is the important part of my code:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int sizeWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec) - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
    int sizeHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    int modeWidth = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int modeHeight = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);

    totalWidth = sizeWidth;

    int width = 0;
    int height = getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();

    int lineWidth = 0;
    int lineHeight = 0;

    int childCount = getChildCount();


    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {

        View child = getChildAt(i);
```

//            child.setMinimumWidth(1080);
            boolean lastChild = i == childCount - 1;

```
        if (child.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {

            if (lastChild) {
                width = Math.max(width, lineWidth);
                height += lineHeight;
            }

            continue;
        }


        Logger.Log("");

        //child.setMinimumWidth(300);
        measureChildWithMargins(child, widthMeasureSpec, lineWidth, heightMeasureSpec, height);

        LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

        int childWidthMode = MeasureSpec.AT_MOST;
        int childWidthSize = sizeWidth;

        int childHeightMode = MeasureSpec.AT_MOST;
        int childHeightSize = sizeHeight;

        if (lp.width == LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) {
            childWidthMode = MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
            childWidthSize -= lp.leftMargin + lp.rightMargin;
        } else if (lp.width >= 0) {
            childWidthMode = MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
            childWidthSize = lp.width;
        }

        if (lp.height >= 0) {
            childHeightMode = MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
            childHeightSize = lp.height;
        } else if (modeHeight == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) {
            childHeightMode = MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED;
            childHeightSize = 0;
        }

        Logger.Log("");

        child.measure(
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childWidthSize, childWidthMode),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childHeightSize, childHeightMode)
        );

        int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth() + lp.leftMargin + lp.rightMargin;

        if (lineWidth + childWidth > sizeWidth) {
            // NEW LINE!!! this code means that the width of the child is bןgger then the space left!
            width = Math.max(width, lineWidth);
            lineWidth = childWidth;

            height += lineHeight;
            lineHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight() + lp.topMargin + lp.bottomMargin;

        } else {
            lineWidth += childWidth;
            lineHeight = Math.max(lineHeight, child.getMeasuredHeight() + lp.topMargin + lp.bottomMargin);
        }

        if (lastChild) {
            width = Math.max(width, lineWidth);
            height += lineHeight;
        }

    }
    // end of loop.

    width += getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();

    setMeasuredDimension(
            (modeWidth == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) ? sizeWidth : width,
            (modeHeight == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) ? sizeHeight : height);
}

/**
 * This method will place each label next to another. If there is not enough
 * space for the next label, it will be added in a new new line.
 * <p>
 */
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {

    mLines.clear();
    mLineHeights.clear();
    mLineMargins.clear();

    int width = getWidth();

    int lineWidth = 0;
    int lineHeight = 0;
    lineViews.clear();

    float horizontalGravityFactor = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {


        View child = getChildAt(i);

        if (child.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            continue;
        }

        LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

        int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth() + lp.leftMargin + lp.rightMargin;
        int childHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight() + lp.bottomMargin + lp.topMargin;

        if (lineWidth + childWidth > width) {
            mLineHeights.add(lineHeight);
            mLines.add(lineViews);
            mLineMargins.add((int) ((width - lineWidth) * horizontalGravityFactor) + getPaddingLeft());

            lineHeight = 0;
            lineWidth = 0;
            lineViews = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        lineWidth += childWidth;
        lineHeight = Math.max(lineHeight, childHeight);
        lineViews.add(child);
    }

    // END OF LOOP.

    mLineHeights.add(lineHeight);
    mLines.add(lineViews);
    mLineMargins.add((int) ((width - lineWidth) * horizontalGravityFactor) + getPaddingLeft());

    int verticalGravityMargin = 0;

    int numLines = mLines.size();

    int left;
    int top = getPaddingTop();

    // now we are looping threw the number of row in total - mLines.size(), and we want to measure each tag!
    for (int i = 0; i < numLines; i++) {

        lineHeight = mLineHeights.get(i);
        // lineViews = number of lines for child!
        lineViews = mLines.get(i);
        left = mLineMargins.get(i);

        int children = lineViews.size();

        for (int j = 0; j < children; j++) {

            View child = lineViews.get(j);

            if (child.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                continue;
            }

            LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

            // if height is match_parent we need to remeasure child to line height
            if (lp.height == LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) {
                int childWidthMode = MeasureSpec.AT_MOST;
                int childWidthSize = lineWidth;

                if (lp.width == LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) {
                    childWidthMode = MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
                } else if (lp.width >= 0) {
                    childWidthMode = MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
                    childWidthSize = lp.width;
                }

                child.measure(
                        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childWidthSize, childWidthMode),
                        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(lineHeight - lp.topMargin - lp.bottomMargin,
                                MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
                );
            }

            int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
            int childHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight();

            int gravityMargin = 0;

            if (Gravity.isVertical(lp.gravity)) {
                switch (lp.gravity) {
                    case Gravity.TOP:
                    default:
                        break;
                    case Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL:
                    case Gravity.CENTER:
                        gravityMargin = (lineHeight - childHeight - lp.topMargin - lp.bottomMargin) / 2;
                        break;
                    case Gravity.BOTTOM:
                        gravityMargin = lineHeight - childHeight - lp.topMargin - lp.bottomMargin;
                        break;
                }
            }

            child.layout(left + lp.leftMargin,
                    top + lp.topMargin + gravityMargin + verticalGravityMargin,
                    left + childWidth + lp.leftMargin,
                    top + childHeight + lp.topMargin + gravityMargin + verticalGravityMargin);



            left += childWidth + lp.leftMargin + lp.rightMargin;

        }
        // end of loop

        top += lineHeight;
    }
    // end of loop

}
```

I would appreciate if you can show me what I have to do to change the size of the child to make it stretched all the way to fill the empty space.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't know what all that code you posted above was doing, too long, too little sense made, don't even know how it worked.

Out of curiosity, I'm gonna try solve this problem directly here, I hope it works.

First the `onMeasure()` method:

```
// maximum available width for children
int maxW = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec) - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();

// you want all children to be as wide as they want, but not wider than the view group
int widthMS = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(w, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
// you probably want them all to have the same height.
// maybe define it in xml attrs?
int heightMS = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(rowHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

// remaining width of current row, initially equals to w
int remW = w;
// index of first child in the current row
int rowFirstChild = 0;
// row count, used to calculate the view group's height
int rows = 0;

int i = 0;
while (i < getChildCount()) {
    Child ch = getChildAt(i);
    if (ch.getVisibility() != View.GONE) {
        // ask how big does it want to be
        child.measure(widthMS, heightMS);

        int chWidth = ch.getMeasuredWidth();

        // if it fits
        if (remW - chWidth >= 0) {
            // update remW, then go to next child
            remW -= chWidth;
            i++;
        } 
        // if it does not fit
        else {
            // if it's not the first child in the row
            if (i > rowFirstChild) {
                stretchViews(rowFirstChild, i - 1, maxW, remW, heightMS);

                // this will be the first child in the next row and take the space from
                // that row's remW
                rowFirstChild = i;
                remW = maxW - chWidth;
            }
            // if it's the first and only child on this row
            else {
                // it should just take the full width and give first spot in the next
                // row to the next child, and reset remW
                rowFirstChild = i + 1;
                remW = maxW;
            }
            // both of these scenarios result in the addition of a new row
            rows++;
        }
    }
}

// finally, we want to take as much width as we can, and as minimum height as we can
int finalW = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
int finalH = Math.min(
    rows * rowHeight + getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(),
    MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec)
);
setMeasuredDimensions(finalW, finalH);

// note that this measurement ignores height measure spec and automatically takes the
// minimum height, and ignores the height measure spec of its children as well and
// just gives them height from its rowHeight attr.
// you are free to change this setting.
```

Now, `onLayout()` method. Here, since we already assigned measurements to our children, they are all set, we simply have to lay them out, not much work to do:

```
// maximum usable width in any row
int maxW = getMeasuredWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();

// left starting point
int left = getPaddingLeft();
// top starting point
int top = getPaddingTop();

int i = 0;
while (i < getChildCount()) {
    Child ch = getChildAt(i);
    if (ch.getVisibility() != GONE) {
        int chWidth = ch.getMeasuredWidth();
        ch.layout(
            left,
            top,
            left + chWidth,
            top + rowHeight
        );

        // if this child is the last in row (-1 for error tolerance when rounding ints)
        if (left + chWidth >= maxW - 1) {
            // reset'left' back to its starting point
            left = getPaddingLeft();
            // move 'top' down by 'rowHeight'
            top += rowHeight;
        }
        // if it wasn't the last child in the row
        else {
            // then simply advance the 'left' position
            left += chWidth;
        }
    }
}

// Note that this method only supports LTR layout.
// You can make minor changes to add support for RTL.
// Also, margins between children are ignored, spend some time on that if you want
```

Let me know if this works

**Update:**

Never mind, I'll just do the stretching method anyway:

```
/**
 * Stretches children of this view group horizontally, and proportionally to their widths
 * to span the entire row width
 *
 * @param firstIndex index of first child to stretch (inclusive)
 * @param lastIndex  index of last child to stretch (inclusive)
 * @param fullWidth  the width to cover (max available width for row children)
 * @param remWidth   remaining width to cover
 * @param heightMS   the hight measure spec to reuse on these views
 */
private void stretchViews(int firstIndex, int lastIndex, int fullWdith, int 
    remWidth, int heightMS) {
    for (int i = firstIndex; i <= lastIndex; i++) {
        Child ch = getChildAt(i);
        if (ch.getVisibility() != GONE) {
            int measuredW = ch.getMeasuredWidth();
            int widthMS = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                measuredW + remWidth * measuredW / fullWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            ch.measure(widthMS, heightMS); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! I tried to do it your way but it didn't worked out... instead i just used                      
params.width = totalWidthChildCanGet+child.getMeasuredWidth();
            params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            child.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: creating new objects in layout/draw passes is discouraged. that's why I used the same old objects (layoutParams) and just remeasured dimens. Anyway, did the whole thing work as (or better than) you expected? if yes, then feel free to accept this answer